# automated actions through xml files

Tags: odoo-14

I managed to make the system send a message as a notification when some expiration date is close

BUT

I created a server action and an automatic action both in the GUI

I'd like to use xml files to create such actions

Otherwise I have to remember to create them every time I create a new db

I [found](https://www.odoo.com/it_IT/forum/assistenza-1/server-actions-and-scheduled-actions-201756) something but for Odoo 15, I'm on Odoo 14

Comment: You can check the [Install Modules](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/data/ir_actions_data.xml) server action

Comment: watching the tables with psql, I can't find a "ir_actions_server" table

There are "ir_actions", "ir_act_server"

I did find odoo/odoo/addons/base/data/ir_actions_data.xml indeed

but I tried to add a simila data file to my project and I can't find my action among the server actions in the GUI

I don't understand what's going on

See here https://imgur.com/a/uEeOzuF

Comment: Go under `Technical / Database Structure / Models` and type `server`, the first item in the list should be `ir.actions.server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation of server actions and automated actions from `XML` are same in Odoo 14.0 or 15.0 and you can check the [Odoo 14.0 Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/actions.html#server-actions-ir-actions-server)

Example for server action:

```
<record id="act_hr_employee_holiday_request" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Time off Analysis</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="hr_holidays.model_hr_leave_report"/>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="hr.model_hr_employee"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
    <field name="code">
    action = model.action_time_off_analysis()
    </field>
</record>
```

[Examples for automated action.](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/saas-14/addons/base_automation/data/base_automation_demo.xml)